# Sort a List of objects based in its Sublist method size

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin, sorting

I'm trying to make my own "Facebook reaction bar" and I got into a problem, I need to sort a list of objects based in its sublist method size, let me explain!

I have a ReactionModel which has a property "usernames" which is a List of Strings of usernames of those users that used it.

I have a list of ReactionModel which represent the reactions, for example this:

```
val reactionsList: List<ReactionModel> = listOf(
ReactionModel(listOf("a","b","c")),
ReactionModel(listOf("z")),
ReactionModel(listOf("f","d"))
)
```

In this case the first one is the largest, after that the third one and finally the second one.

I need to sort the reactionList and got a decreasing of it based on the size of usernames property.

**Input:**

```
ReactionModel(listOf("a","b","c")),
ReactionModel(listOf("z")),
ReactionModel(listOf("f","d"))
```

**Output:**

```
ReactionModel(listOf("z")),
ReactionModel(listOf("f","d")),
ReactionModel(listOf("a","b","c"))
```

I tried using forEach's but without success. I found some question here but is comparing just two list. Hope to find any answer, thanks for your time!!

**Edit:**
Is for Android, so the answer can be in Java or Kotlin

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. It is actually, I'm not seeing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortedBy` can be used for this, I'm assuming the name of the `string` list in `ReactionModel` is `stringList`.

```
 val sortedList = reactionsList.sortedBy {
                        it.stringList.size
                  }
```

`sortedBy` doesn't change the existing `list`, but returns the `sorted` list.

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin, you can do it using single line,

```
reactionsList.sortedByDescending { it.{getYourListHere}.size }
```